# Why is 'dsgaudiko' valid PHP?

Tags: compiler-errors, php

Wondering how I should go about the next thing I typed a random string in a PHP file, between `<?` and `?>`. I was curious what error this would produce, so I uploaded it and watched.

But no error, only a blank screen. Why? Does the PHP compiler ignore pieces of code that don't look like PHP?

the PHP file:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <?
            dsgaudiko
        ?>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

See it in action [here](http://korilu.nl/maurits/iets.php).

Comment: You probably have some the PHP set up to silently fail, without outputting error messages. Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that means your error reporting is suppressed.

To watch the error message - http://codepad.viper-7.com/I0Fj9v

[PHP Error Reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: My error reporting is not suppressed, if I type `dsgaudiko()` instead it says `call to undefined function ...`.

Comment: there are different [levels of error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) in your first case you have *Parse error* which is a softer one, in case of `saffsad()` - that's a *Fatal error* - http://codepad.viper-7.com/btKbeF

Comment: depends what level it is set up, you can show some but not other errors

Answer (score 0):

Enable PHP notices,

This is what I am getting with your code:

`Notice: Use of undefined constant dsgaudiko - assumed 'dsgaudiko'`

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <br />
        <b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant dsgaudiko - assumed 'dsgaudiko' in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/desecration/index.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```